# Executing OpenShift commands with Python SSH utility failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, openshift, paramiko

I'm trying to execute Open Shift commands like `oc get nodes` on a openshift node using Python Paramiko SSH client.

When I run this command directly on node it executes and returns output. But, if I try executing it using ssh session it throws below error.

```
['error: Missing or incomplete configuration info. Please login or point to an existing, complete config file:', '',
'1. Via the command-line flag --config',
'2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable',
'3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config', '',
"To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command."]
```

The code I wrote is as follows:

```py
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=ip_address,
                   username=username,
                   password=password)
    client.exec_command('oc get nodes')
```

Even tried running command using `ssh -i oc get nodes`, this throws Bash: oc command does not exist.

Python Version used: Python3.7

I'm new to Python let me know if there is any library I can use to execute oc commands.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Look like the session it opens using Paramiko from python and normal ssh are different. Because when i run `oc config view` it returns blank from paramiko.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python library, you can use: https://pypi.org/project/openshift-client/

```
import openshift as oc
oc.set_default_kubeconfig_path("/path/to/kubeconfig")
oc.selector('node').names()
```

To fix your issue: you need to add the kubeconfig path:

```
client.exec_command('oc get nodes --kubeconfig <path to kubeconfig on host>')
```